# Which approach should I use for generating + inserting 100+ records into a SQL table

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

### Some facts about my data

1. I have a `TablePattern` that defines periodic day pattern (usually long from few days and up to 28)
2. Day pattern is stored as `varbinary(4)` as bit flags. Some days are on (set to 1 == *true*), others are off (set to 0 == *false*). There's also `Length` column that defines pattern length stored in the binary column
3. Each pattern record also has information whether weekends and holidays nullify pattern settings (explained later)
4. I have table `Holidays` that defines holidays (some repeatable others fixed on a particular year)
5. I have `TableCalendar` where I need to create X number of records. One for each day.

### The problem

When generating records

1. I know which pattern to use
2. I know date range of days whose records I have to create
3. Along with pattern I also know whether weekends/holidays take presence over pattern settings - this means that when I will be generating records it will automatically set them to `false` even though pattern says it should be *true*
4. I also have additional `Offset` that tells me how to apply the pattern to my date range - if `offset == 0` pattern starts at the first day; `offset == 3` pattern starts on fourth day; offset is **always** between 0 and pattern length less 1 (in range of pattern length modulo values)
5. all days before offset also have to be set as if pattern has started earlier (before starting day of the date range)

### Questions

I have basically two options:

1. I can generate calendar data on the middle tier, which would make it simpler, but would require a lot of DB calls to insert each record into `TableCalendar`.
2. I can write a stored procedure and provide it:

   - date range
   - pattern record ID
   - offset

   and then write all the logic that would generate and insert records into `TableCalendar`. I can't even imagine how to write this complex stored procedure that would use binary pattern and apply it with offsets etc.

Date ranges will usually be 1, 3 and 12 months long the second one being the most frequent one.

And since this generation is part of a web application's Ajax call it has to be as snappy as possible. That's the only reason I suppose that generating all records with a singe DB call would be faster than making lots of DB calls and execute some extremely simple insert statement. But I'm pretty sure that SP will become quite complex hance can also become sluggish.

**What would you suggest I should do?**

You can as well provide some TSQL code that would show how to generate those records using data I provided in a stored procedure.

Comment: did you try red-gate's sql server data generator? http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/

Comment: @M.R. I have to generate these during my usual program business process execution. It's not an external task. When user comes to a point when these need to be created they should be created and with certain values, not just some random values that a generator would create. It's the same as if a user would be adding a product to a database (with specific data). But instead of inserting only one, they would be adding hundreds with similar data but not completely the same.

Comment: Is the data specific to the user, or each instance? Or is it the same data that will get inserted for all users?

Comment: @M.R. It's the data that is related to what **users** have entered in the system. When they run the process, calendar data should be generated based on other values in other tables and data provided by users in the moment of execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do know you can insert multiple row in one insert.  If you can sort your data by the clustered index you will get much faster insert.  Change your fill on SQL.  TSQL does not like more than 999 rows so I load 900 rows at a time.  It is pretty fast - I am inserting 1,000 rows a second on a slow server.

```
    Insert Into [WFbchDocs] with (holdlock)
    ([wfID], [bchID], [sID], [folderID]) Values 
     ('1','11','2','1') 
    ,('1','11','3','1') 
    ,('1','11','4','1')
```

Comment: No I wasn't aware of such `insert` statement. Thanks. This means I can generate my records on the middle tier and then generate such long(er) statement and insert in one go. Great.

Comment: **Two additional questions for you though:** **First** I was reading about `holdlock` but I don't seem to understand the idea. What would be different if this table hint wasn't used? **Second** When you say *sort data by clustered index* do you mean if I provide records so they're specified in the order of the clustered index? What if my clustered index was identity column which I (of course) don't provide in the values? Does it matter then?

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm not familiar with some of the specifics, I'm not sure how much help I can give, but here's a couple of suggestions I can make.

1. I'm not certain it would be more efficient, but it is possible to make CLR functions for SQL server. This would allow you to make the complex code you are familiar with in the .Net language of your choice and make that procedure available to SQL Server.
2. There may be some specifics you are dealing with that I am not understanding, but based on what I have read so far, you might have some success writing a stored procedure using "Common Table Expressions" that may help to make the procedures less complicated.

If you can give more specifics as to your inputs and expected outputs, I might be able to give you a more concrete example.